# SQL - get substraction between 2 records

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

I have a question about SQL (I use MySQL), I don't know if it's possible but I ask you.
I am currently doing a particular query, but I am not able to implement this.
The image in below of this message, is a table where there are result of the top 2 result (by `best` column) in each country.

The query that I would like to implement  this is getting difference between top2 and top1 in `countryRank` in each `countryId`. I would like to have the result like this:

| countryId | difference (2-1) |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 30 |
| Albania | 83 |
| ... | ... |

**Attention:** some country doesn't have value `2` as `countryRank` like Angola in image, in this case I would like to ignore this.

[image: ranking]

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Please post the table data as texts and not as image.

Comment: Since it doesn't have `rank=2` then what would the result for `Angola` be?  `0-2563 = -2563`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a single query like this:

```
SELECT countryId,
       MAX(IF(countryRank=2,best,0)) - MAX(IF(countryRank=1,best,0)) AS "difference (2-1)"
 FROM mytable
GROUP BY countryId;
```

But on a country where there's no `rank=2` (like `Angola`), the result will return negative `-2563`.

| countryId | difference (2-1) |
| --- | --- |
| Afghan | 30 |
| Albania | 83 |
| Algeria | 399 |
| Andorra | 158 |
| Angola | -2563 |
| Argentina | 33 |
| Armenia | 105 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9eb9477dce821f1c0d0506765e40cfaf)

Answer (score 0):

Split the recordset into two and use a join or use a window function. Sample here in the [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08ed6ad5d42f3183397625e34785b7cd).